# Where's the list of connections of conjectures list on wikipedia?

Tags: conjectures

Where's the list of connections of conjectures list on Wikipedia?

There's an OEIS sequence that partially connects Collatz and Goldbach, as 2 mod 4 numbers having Goldbach partitions formed via it's members, should imply a Goldbach partition for the number around the bend.

Twin prime implies, infinitely many 0 mod 12 numbers have Goldbach partitions,

Green-Tao ( a Theorem not a Conjecture) implies infinitely many arithmetic progressions of even numbers have Goldbach partitions.

Cunningham chains of first kind, imply that if $n$ has a Goldbach partition where both aren't end members ( or the only ones in lentth 1 chains ...) then 2n+2 will have one ...

As you can see, There are quite a few even towards Goldbach.

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_mathematics

Comment: I was looking for something of a connections between members list of that one